# Camtasia html page Video does not play when uploaded to Server

Tags: html, upload, camtasia

The graphic designer created a camtasia video yesterday and im just trying to upload it to our production server. When i navigate to the html page the video and screenshot of the video show without issue. When i click play the media bar shows up down the bottom but nothing will play.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your web server may need to have the MIME types for the Flash MP4 format configured?

This article might help - [MP4/FLV/SWF Flash plays on local machine, but not from server or network](http://techsmith.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/techsmith.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=547)

Whoever manages your web server should be familiar with setting up the MIME types and can check with Adobe if you have further questions.